# Can I change the type of Model Field?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-south

Say, I have a model with this field:

```
is_retired = models.NullBooleanField()
```

It has never been set for any of the records i the database, so I think all the records will have a null value for this field.

And now want to change it to a string field:

```
is_retired = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I am using Django 1.7 and ran `makemigrations` which seemed to go fine, said something about altered field. However, when I actually run the `migrate` command it fails with

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "is_retired" contains null values
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enable null/empty values, change it to:

```
is_retired = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

You might also want to change the null values to empty strings ('') in another migration.

Comment: Is it okay to do this? I read in "two scoops of Django" that it wasn't a good idea to null=True in a CharField?

Comment: You already have null values there. Once you get rid of them (`.filter(is_retired=None).update(is_retired='')`), you can remove the null=True part.

Comment: Still get same error. I think it make be trying to apply the same migration before the new one perhaps? Not sure how South / 1.7 works to stop this?

Comment: Just remove the failing migration and create a new one, this time with null=True.

Ideally, you would then have a second migration ([data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)) changing the nulls to empty strings, and a third one with null=True removed from the field.